# Appium Chrome driver port 9515

Tags: appium

I am able to execute the script for the first with appium, selenium and C# on android device. But whenever I try to run the script next time I am getting below error.

info: [CHROMEDRIVER STDERR] [0.028][SEVERE]: Could not bind socket to 0.0.0.0:9515
 info: [CHROMEDRIVER] Port not available. Exiting...
 info: Chromedriver exited with code 1
 ERROR: debug: executing: "c:\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 4d00b33d4ae241bf devices
 info: [ADB] Getting connected devices...
 info: [ADB] 1 device(s) connected

ERROR: debug: executing: "c:\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 4d00b33d4ae241bf shell "am force-stop com.android.chrome"

ERROR: error: Chromedriver create session did not work. Status was 200 and body was {"sessionId":"79cdf9fec37fb4700e10ce34566a7e11","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: Device 4d00b33d4ae241bf is already in use\n (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)"}}

ERROR: error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver

But if I change the Chrome driver port from 9515 to something else the script is getting executed. Then againw henever I want to execute the script, I have to change the Chrome driver port to something new from the existing one. My OS is windows 7. Need help in this matter.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are not closing the driver instance after the script run so the acquired port is not free for next run.

Possible Solutions:

- Findout the process of Chromedriver and stop it
- Restart Appium server
- Try with driver.quit() or equivalent at the end point of your script